# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!' in

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am currently using rackspace cloudsites and my wordpress config is not connecting.

Here is the error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '!' in /mnt/stor7-wc1-dfw1/672237/www.site.com/web/content/wp-config.php on line 28

Line 28 seems to be the password field:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', ' 672207_wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '672207_wpusers');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', ‘!Password’);

/** MySQL hostname */
```

Comment: You have wrong quotes `‘!Password’` change to `'!Password'` also please donot use the original credentials in your question

Comment: i like how the syntax highlighting here makes it so much more obvious than it likely is in the editor being used.

Answer (score 4):

The parse error comes from using  curly/smart quotes in `‘!Password’`

Change it to `'!Password'`

They're beautiful, yet *deadly*.

This may have been caused by using a Word Processor such as Word or similar, or copied from a Website, or the type of quotes on your keyboard.

An IDE would have picked this up.

---

As stated by Kevin B [`in a comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848367/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in#comment34854744_22848367), notice how the word "Password" shows up in light blue?

StackOverflow's syntax highlighting has done its job and was a sign.

Answer (score 0):

use `define('DB_PASSWORD', '!Password');` instead of `define('DB_PASSWORD', ‘!Password’);`

The correct code:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', ' 672207_wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '672207_wpusers');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '!Password');

/** MySQL hostname */
```

Comment: When correcting someone's code you should also explain why it did not work, and why your correction does work. It may be obvious if you know what you are doing, but if they had to ask then it is probably not obvious to them.